# Can a custom guard mechanism be defined in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, design-patterns, guard

If you look at the example for `catches`:

```
 f = expr `catches` [Handler (\ (ex :: ArithException) -> handleArith ex),
                     Handler (\ (ex :: IOException)    -> handleIO    ex)]
```

It looks like `catches` has defined a custom mechanism to match on patterns (the two exception types). Am I mistaken, or can this be generalized to allow one to define a function that can take lambda functions that match on a certain pattern?

Edit: FYI below is the GHC source for catches. If someone can shed some light on how this works it would be great.

```
catches :: IO a -> [Handler a] -> IO a
catches io handlers = io `catch` catchesHandler handlers

catchesHandler :: [Handler a] -> SomeException -> IO a
catchesHandler handlers e = foldr tryHandler (throw e) handlers
    where tryHandler (Handler handler) res
              = case fromException e of
                Just e' -> handler e'
                Nothing -> res
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the [Scoped Type Variables](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Scoped_type_variables) GHC extension at work. Follow the link to learn more.

Basically, you define an assertion about type that have to be met by the patter before it can match. So, yeah, it is akin to guards, but not completely so.

How this particular example works? Dive into [sources of "base" library](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/src/Control-Exception-Base.html) to find out that:

```
class (Show e) => Exception e where
    toException   :: e -> SomeException
    fromException :: SomeException -> Maybe e

data SomeException = forall e . Exception e => SomeException e

instance Exception IOException where
    toException = IOException
    fromException (IOException e) = Just e
    fromException _ = Nothing

instance Exception ArithException where
    toException = ArithException
    fromException (ArithException e) = Just e
    fromException _ = Nothing
```

We see that `IOException` and `ArithException` are different types implementing the typeclass `Exception`. We also see that `toException/fromException` is a wrapping/unwrapping mechanism that allows one to convert values of type `Exception` to/from values of types `IOException`, `ArithException`, etc.

So, we could've written:

```
f = expr `catches` [Handler handleArith,
                    Handler handleIO]

handleArith :: ArithException -> IO ()
handleArith ex = ....

handleIO :: IOException -> IO ()
handleIO ex = ....
```

Suppose that `IOException` happens. When `catchesHandler` processes first element of the handlers list, it calls `tryHandler`, which calls `fromException`. From the definition of `tryHandler` it follows that return type of the `fromException` should be the same as argument of `handleArith`. On the other hand, `e` is of type Exception, namely - (IOException ...). So, the types play out this way (this is not a valid haskell, but I hope that you get my point):

```
fromException :: (IOException ...) -> Maybe ArithException
```

From the `instance Exception IOException ...` it follows immediately that the result is `Nothing`, so this handler is skipped. By the same reasoning the following handler would be called, because `fromException` would return `(Just (IOException ...))`.

So, you've used type signatures of `handleArith` and `handleIO` to specify when each of them would be called, and `fromException/toException` made sure that it happened this way.

If you want to, you could also constraint types of `handleIO` and `handleArith` inside the definition of `f`, using scoped type variables. Arguably, this could give you better readability.

Finalizing, Scoped Type Variables are not a primary players here. They are just used for convenience. Main machinery for playing this kind of tricks is `fromException/toException` and friends. Scoped Type Variables just allow you to have syntax which more closely resemble guard patterns.

Comment: How are scoped type variables involved? I don't see this mechanism at work in the source of catches.

Answer (score 1):

```
case () of 
  ()| foo expr1 -> handleFooCase
    | bar expr2 -> handleBarCase
    | otherwise -> blah
```